# Como recuperar commit removido?

Tags: git

Considere a seguinte história:

1. No repositório local fiz o commit A e B.
2. Fiz push para o repositório no servidor.
3. Voltei ao repositório local e fiz alterações.
4. Removi o commit B do repositório local (utilizando o comando abaixo) antes de fazer commit das novas alterações:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

Como faço para recuperar o commit removido do repositório local de modo que o histórico fique igual ao repositório do servidor e **sem perder as alterações** que ainda não foram comitadas?

Comment: `git reflog` para listar todos os commits (inclusive os em *floating state*), e `git merge [SHA1]` para trazê-lo de volta ao repositório.

Comment: @OnoSendai Sim, era isso, resolveu o problema e não perdi minhas alterações. Por favor, adicione uma resposta para aceita-la como certa. Obrigado.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes fique à vontade para implementar a resposta descrevendo o seu processo e aceitá-la. E fico feliz que tenha funcionado pra você. =)

Answer (score 1):

Felipe

> Para recuperar um commit do reset – HARD, basta usar git reflog.

---

Fonte: http://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/9-dicas-muito-uteis-para-trabalhar-melhor-com-git/